# Google script to get folder names within a parent folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, directory

I need to get the names and URLs of the folders in a specified folder.

This is my attempt:

```
// set the folder to pull folder names from
var DDparentid = "IDhere";
var DDparent = DriveApp.getFolderById(DDparentid);
var DDfolders = DDparent.getFolders();

// iterate through folders in the folder
while (DDfolders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = DDfolders.next();

    // get folder name
    Logger.log(folder.getName());

    var DDnames = folder.getName();

    // get the url       
    Logger.log(folder.getUrl());

    var DDURLs = folder.getUrl();
}
```

This works for get file URLs, but I believe that folders are treated differently, and getfolder is used differently. I get an error stating that a string is not suitable in DriveApp.getfolder(). How should I be using getfolder?

EDITED: this runs, buit doesn't actually pull URLs or folder names. Both variables are undefined, but there are no errors.

Comment: Are you sure that your are using the right folder id?

Comment: It works, the error was with another part of the code not depicted here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Next time create a [mcve] :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this :

```
var parentFolderId = "xxxxxxxIDxxxxxxx";
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
var folders = parentFolder.getFolders();
var folder;
// iterate through folders in the folders fetched from parent folder
while (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
    // get folder name
    Logger.log(folder.getName());
    // get the url       
    Logger.log(folder.getUrl());
}
```

This is an un-tested code, let me know if any issue arises I'll be happy to help us.

Thanks

Comment: it runs, but for some reason the URLs and folder names are not being recorded. The variables I set equal to the folder.getname() and folder.getUrl() are undefined, and the array that is built from those variables is also undefined. So I'm not actually pulling the names or URLs.

Comment: It works for files without a problem, but doesn't seem to work with folders?

Comment: Umair, your original code works for me. Perhaps you are encountering a caching or latency problem. Also - I've seen strange things where something like Logger.log(folder.getUrl()) won't work, but if you break it up into two lines like x=folder.getUrl();  Logger.log(x); - then it will work. Not sure why.

Comment: Sorry guys, for late reply. I have tested my code and it seems to work fine for me. If you can tell me little more details about what you're expecting out of this or what you want to achieve then may be I'll be able to help you guys more.

Answer (score 1):

Below lists all subfolder name and URL for specified folder:

```
function listSubFoldersInFolder(id) {
  var dfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('ENTER_PARENT_FOLDER_ID_HERE');
  var contents = dfolder.getFolders();
  var file;
  var name;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var link;

  sheet.clear();
  sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Link"]);


  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = file.getUrl();
    data = [name, link]
    sheet.appendRow(data);
  }
};
```